# Replace a value on one data set with a value from another data set with a dynamic lookup

Tags: python, r, alteryx

This question relates primarly to Alteryx, however if it can be done in Python, or R in Alteryx workflow using the R tool then that would work as well.

I have two data sets.

Address (contains address information: Line1, Line2, City, State, Zip)

USPS (contains USPS abbreviations: Street to ST, Boulevard to BLVD, etc.)

Goal: Look at the string on the Address data set for Line1.  IF it CONTAINS one of the types of streets in the USPS data set, I want to replace that part of the string with its proper abbreviation which is in a different column of the USPS data set.

Example, 123 Main Street would become 123 Main St

What I have tried:
Imported the two data sets.
Union the two data sets with the instruction of Output All Fields for When Fields Differ.
Added a formula, but this is where I am getting stuck.  So far it reads:

```
if [Addr1] Contains(Sting, Target)
```

Not sure how to have it look in the USPS for one of the values.  I am also not certain if this sort of dynamic lookup can take place.

If this can be done in python (I know very basic Python so I don't have code for this yet because I do not know where to start other than importing the data) I can use python within Alteryx.

Any assistance would be great.  Please let me know if you need additional information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall logic that can be used is here: [Using str_detect (or some other function) and some way to loop through a list to essentially perform a vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397445/using-str-detect-or-some-other-function-and-some-way-to-loop-through-a-list-to)

However, in order to expand to Alteryx, you would need to add the Alteryx R tool.  Also, some of the code would need to be changed to use the syntax that Alteryx likes.

read in the data with:

```
read.Alteryx('#Link Number', mode = 'data.frame')
```

After, the above linked question will provide the overall framework for the logic.  Reiterated here:

```
usps[] = lapply(usps, as.character)
##Copies the original address data to a new column that will
##be altered.  Preserves the orignal formatting for rollback 
##if necessary
vendorData$new_addr1 = as.character(vendorData$Addr1)

##Loops through the dictionary replacing all of the common names
##with their USPS approved abbreviations for the Addr1 field.
for(i in 1:nrow(usps)) {
  vendorData$new_addr1 = str_replace_all(
    vendorData$new_addr1,
    pattern = paste0("\\b", usps$Abbreviation[i], "\\b"),
    replacement = usps$USPS_Abbrv_updated[i]
  )
}
```

Finally, in order to be able to see the output, we would need to write a statement that will output it in one of the 5 output slots the R tool has.  Here is the code for that:

```
write.Alteryx(data, #)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Find Replace tool in Alteryx. This tool is akin to a lookup. Furthermore, use the Alteryx Community as a go to for these types of questions.

Input the Address dataset into the top anchor of the Find Replace tool and the USPS dataset into the bottom anchor. You'll want to find any part of the address field using the lookup field and replace it with the abbreviation field. If you need to do this across several fields in the Address dataset, then you could replicate this logic or you could use a Record ID tool, Transpose, run this logic on one field, and then Cross Tab back to the original schema. It's an advanced recipe that you'll want to master in Alteryx.

https://help.alteryx.com/current/FindReplace.htm