# Using str_detect (or some other function) and some way to loop through a list to essentially perform a vlookup

Tags: r, stringr

I have been searching for a way to do this and some results on here seem similar, nothing seems to be working, nor can I find a method that will loop through a list like a vlookup in excel.  I apologize if I have missed it.

I am trying to add a new column to a data set with Mutate.  What it is going to do is look at one column using str_replace (or some other function if necessary), and then loop through another list.  I want to replace what it finds on with the corresponding value in another column.  Essentially a vlookup in excel.  It cannot be done in excel however because the file is simply too large.

I can do a simple str_replace one at a time, but there are 502 possible options that I need to choose from, so writing the code for that would take a very long time.  Here is what I have so far:

```
 testVendor <- vendorData %>%
  select(TOUPPER(Addr1) %>%
  mutate('NewAdd' = str_replace(Addr1, 'STREET', 'ST'))
```

However, rather than me specifying STREET and then ST, I want it to loop through a list of common postal abbreviations and return the standard abbreviation.

An example would be

```
addr1 <- c('123 MAIN STREET', '123 GARDEN ROAD', '123 CHARLESTON BOULEVARD')
state_abbrv <- c('FL', 'CA', 'NY')
vendor <- data.frame(addr1, state_abbrv)
usps_name <- c('STREET', 'LANE', 'BOULEVARD', 'ROAD', 'TURNPIKE')
usps_abbrv <- c('ST', 'LN', 'BLVD', 'RD', 'TPKE')
usps <- data.frame(usps_name, usps_abbrv)
```

The ideal output would be a new column on the vendor data frame and would look like this:

[image: Example Output]

Any assistance with this is wonderful, and please allot me to expand on the question if it is unclear of what I am looking for.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and show the expected output. The nicest way to add sample data is so it is copy/pasteable. `dput()` is helpful for this, e.g., `dput(droplevels(your_data[1:5, ]))`

Comment: I guess you could create a table with the replacements and original words, make a function that with an word returns the answer, apply this function to all your phrases, it probably also sucks in terms of performance but you can actually paralyze this operation

Comment: So one table has only the common name and the abbreviation for the common name as defined by the USPS.  The other table has the full address.  What I am looking to do is replace Street with ST.  If merging will assist with a vlookup type situation then please show how that would go.  Basically, it is going come to first line and say ok, it contains street, lets loop through this other table until I find street.  Then it will give the item in the next column over instead of the word street.  It will then move to line 2 and repeat the same process.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a for loop:

```
usps[] = lapply(usps, as.character)
vendor$new_addr1 = as.character(vendor$addr1)

for(i in 1:nrow(usps)) {
  vendor$new_addr1 = str_replace_all(
    vendor$new_addr1, 
    pattern = usps$usps_name[i], 
    replacement = usps$usps_abbrv[i])
}

vendor
#                      addr1 state_abbrv           new_addr1
# 1          123 MAIN STREET          FL         123 MAIN ST
# 2          123 GARDEN ROAD          CA       123 GARDEN RD
# 3 123 CHARLESTON BOULEVARD          NY 123 CHARLESTON BLVD
```

To be extra safe, I'd add regex word boundaries to your patterns, as below, so that only whole words are replaced. (I assume you want AIRPLANE RD changed to AIRPLANE RD, not AIRPLN RD)

```
for(i in 1:nrow(usps)) {
  vendor$new_addr1 = str_replace_all(
    vendor$new_addr1, 
    pattern = paste0("\\b", usps$usps_name[i], "\\b"), 
    replacement = usps$usps_abbrv[i])
}
```

Comment: This absolute works!  Thought a comma is required at the end of 'pattern' line.  Tried to make the edit, but since it was not 6 char long, it would not let me.  Fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of the most confusing r code that I have ever written but it kind of solves the problem

```
library(tidyverse)

df_phrases <- tribble(~phrases,
                      "testing this street for pests",
                      "this street better be lit")

df_lookup <- tribble(~word,~replacement,
                     "street","st",
                     "pests","rats",
                     "lit","well iluminated")

lookup_function <- function(phrase,df_lookup){
  wordss <- phrase %>% 
    str_split(" ")

  table_to_join <- tibble(word = wordss) %>% unnest()

  table_to_join %>%
    left_join(df_lookup) %>% 
    mutate(new_vector = if_else(replacement %>% is.na,
                                word,
                                replacement)) %>% 
    pull(new_vector) %>% 
    str_flatten(collapse = " ")

  # words_to_replace <- map(wordss,function(x) x %in% c(df_lookup$word))
  # tibble(wordss,words_to_replace) %>%
  #   unnest()
}

   df_phrases%>%
  mutate(test = phrases %>% map_chr(lookup_function,df_lookup))
```